# Usar JQuery para trocar textos

Tags: html, jquery

Bom dia!

Não tenho acesso ao HTML de um site que estou editando, por isso pra fazer adições, só consigo via css ou js. Basicamente preciso trocar um texto de "serviço", para "Transfer" e to tentando com jquery no "Javascript no header", que tem no WP.

Sou bem amador em JS então não sei dizer onde está o erro. Estou tentando usar o Firebug pra achar problemas, mas a princípio o código nem aparece nele.

Segue codigo de como está agora

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('service').text('Transfer');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label class="service">
  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="Service" id="package-service-toggle">
  <span></span>
  <p>Serviço</p>
</label>
```

Comment: Mas você consegue ver o código-fonte e poderia postar o trecho que você quer alterar na pergunta.

Comment: basicamente não vai funcionar, porque você fez um selector para buscar um elemento da tag "service", como se fosse "table", "body" ou "p", não acho que seja o caso. Se service for um id ou classe, precisa rever o seletor. Coloque o html pra que possamos ajudar

Comment: Segue HTML <label class="service"><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="Service" id="package-service-toggle"><span></span><p>Serviço</p></label>  O ID que tenho que escolher seria então "package-service-togglw"?

Comment: Adicione o código na pergunta, é só clicar em [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/329660/edit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você vai conseguir desta forma:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#package-service-toggle')
    .closest('.service')
    .find('p')
    .text('Transfer');
});
```

Como podem ter outros elementos com a classe `.service`, selecione o `id` do input, busque o elemento pai que possua a classe `.service` e em seguida busque pela tag `<p>`, que só tem uma:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#package-service-toggle')
    .closest('.service')
    .find('p')
    .text('Transfer');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="service">
  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="Service" id="package-service-toggle">
  <span></span>
  <p>Serviço</p>
</label>
```

Ou pode usar JavaScript *puro* que faz a mesma coisa:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
   document.querySelector('#package-service-toggle')
   .parentNode.querySelector('p')
   .textContent = 'Transfer';
});
```

**Exemplo:**

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
   document.querySelector('#package-service-toggle')
   .parentNode.querySelector('p')
   .textContent = 'Transfer';
});
```

```html
<label class="service">
  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="Service" id="package-service-toggle">
  <span></span>
  <p>Serviço</p>
</label>
```

> Talvez seja necessário fazer a alteração após o carregamento completo
>   da página. Para isso altere o `$(document).ready(function(){` para
>   `$(window).on('load', function(){`.

Comment: Ainda não consegui. O codigo agora está assim  <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    $('p', '.service').text('Transfer');

});
</script>

Comment: Alterei a resposta. Veja agora.

Comment: Ainda não consegui. Estou colocando precisamente assim     <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#package-service-toggle')
    .closest('.service')
    .find('p')
    .text('Transfer');
});
</script>      Em teoria o WP já vem com essa biblioteca instalada então e como não tenho acesso ao HTML, só tenho como colocar esse cod usando o bloco "codigo js customizado", que é onde to colando. No caso na Header.

Comment: Dá uma olhada no console e veja se aparece algum erro

Comment: Nenhum relacionado a isso, segue link do site. Dentro da pagina estou tentando trocar o termo do motor de busca "monte sua viagem" de "serviço" para "transfer". https://viagens.apino.com.br/rd-summit-2018/

Comment: Funcionou sam! tks!

Comment: Blz. vou inserir na resposta porque pode ajudar quem tiver o mesmo problema. Abs!

Answer (score 0):

O problema pode ser no seletor que você está usando. Pois `$("service")` faz com o jQuery procure por um elemento `<service>` no DOM, o que acho pouco provável que aconteça. Veja:

```
$('service'); // Procura por <service>
$('#service'); // Procura por <??? id="service" />
$('.service'); // Procura por <??? class="service" />
```

Um exemplo funcional:

```js
console.log('$("p"): ', $('p').html());   // Busca por tag
console.log('$("#p"): ', $('#p').html()); // Busca por id
console.log('$(".p"): ', $('.p').html()); // Busca por class
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<h3 id="p">id == "p"</h3>
<p>tag == "p"</p>
<div class="p">class == "p"</div>
```

Você pode checar a [documentação do jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) para ver mais opções de seletores.

Answer (score 0):

O erro é que não foi bem especificado para o jQuery qual elemento você deseja manipular.

Portanto, como o service é um **class** deve-se colocar **"."** dentro do seletor do jQuery. E faltou navegar até o seu parágrafo.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.service p').html('Transfer');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label class="service">
    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="Service" id="package-service-toggle">
    <span></span>
    <p>Serviço</p>
</label>
```