# Trocar texto de botão ao clicar com JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Boa tarde!

Estou tentando trocar o texto de um botão sempre que ele for clicado. (ONCLICK) O problema?
Bom, aparentemente todos os botões tem a mesma class e eu não tenho acesso ao HTML, apenas ao js e css do WP.. Existe alguma forma de eu adicionar uma class especifica pra fazer isso funcionar?

Codigo jquery

```
<script> 
$(window).on('click', function(){ 

$('a', '.price')

.text('SELECIONADO'); 

}); 

</script>
```

Cod HTML

```
<p class="price"><a href="#" class="purchase" title="Selecionar">SELECIONADO</a></p>
```

Detalhe importante: Esqueci  que mesmo que eu resolva isso, ainda preciso complementar o codigo para que ao clicar em outro botão, o anterior volte para "Selecionar" e o novo clicado fique com "Selecionado".

Todos eles tem a mesma linha, a unica diferença é uma "hashkkey" que vem depois da class

```
<li class="hotel_block hotelContainer selected" hashkey="1214192">
   <figure>
      <p class="thumb no_image hide"></p>
      <img class="thumbImageUrl" src="https://www.travelagent.com.br/uploadImages//6b36d85b-537c-4f87-a563-a51d9e49a593.jpg">
   </figure>
   <div class="content">
      <h3 class="name">Maria do Mar Hotel |REGIÃO CENTRAL|</h3>
      <p class="stars star3">
         <span class="rating-foreground">
            <meta itemprop="rating" content="3">
         </span>
      </p>
      <div class="hotel_group">
         <span class="easter-egg">
            Id: 1214192 <br>HotelOffline - 1214192
            <br>
         </span>
         <p class="address">
            Rodovia João Paulo, 2285 - João Paulo - 88030-300
         </p>
         <p class="distance downtown">
            6.22 km<small>A 6.22 km&nbsp;do centro da cidade</small>
         </p>
         <p class="distance airport">
            13.32 km<small>A 13.32 km do aeroporto FLN- Hercilio Luz, Brasil (FLN)</small>
         </p>
         <p class="short-description">
            Hotel econômico no bairro João Paulo a poucos quilômetros do Centro, com vista para a Baía Norte, ampla área verde, hidro externa, jardim de inverno, piscina, playground, sala de jogos, quad...
         </p>
      </div>
      <a href="#" class="details show hotel btnhotelDetails" title="Detalhes">Detalhes</a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="observation showObservations btn">Observações</a>
   </div>
   <div class="details boxhotelDetails masterprice"></div>
   <div class="rooms_options">
      <div class="room_header hide">
         <ul class="tab tabRoomButtons">
            <li class="itemBtnTabRoom selected">
               <a href="#" class="btnTabRoom" title="Quarto 1">Quarto 1</a>
            </li>
         </ul>
         <p class="help">
            <small>Escolha uma opção de quarto para cada um dos quartos que você solicitou na pesquisa</small>
         </p>
      </div>
      <div class="rooms_group">
         <div class="room_group show">
            <ul class="listRooms rooms">
               <li class="roomsgroup_room price price_even selected show" roomhashkey="475601">
                  <label>
                     <input type="radio" checked="" name="room-1214192-0" class="select_btn room buy " roomhashkey="475601">
                     <div>
                        <p class="name">Standard Single </p>
                        <p class="services">Cafe da Manha</p>
                        <a href="#" class="imageRoom more_pics showImagesRoom">SELECIONADO</a>
                        <p class="price price-exchange" originalcurrency="BRL" displayexchangerate="undefined" originalprice="227">
                           R$ 227,00
                        </p>
                        <p class="priceSufixx">Diária</p>
                     </div>
                  </label>
               </li>
               <li class="roomsgroup_room price price_odd hide" roomhashkey="458842">
                  <label>
                     <input type="radio" name="room-1214192-0" class="select_btn room buy selected" roomhashkey="458842">
                     <div>
                        <p class="name">Standard Casal</p>
                        <p class="services">Cafe da Manha</p>
                        <p class="price price-exchange" originalcurrency="BRL" displayexchangerate="undefined" originalprice="268">
                           R$ 268,00
                        </p>
                        <p class="priceSufixx">Diária</p>
                     </div>
                  </label>
               </li>
               <li class="roomsgroup_room price price_even hide" roomhashkey="475489">
                  <label>
                     <input type="radio" name="room-1214192-0" class="select_btn room buy selected" roomhashkey="475489">
                     <div>
                        <p class="name">Standard Twin</p>
                        <p class="services">Cafe da Manha</p>
                        <a href="#" class="imageRoom more_pics showImagesRoom">SELECIONADO</a>
                        <p class="price price-exchange" originalcurrency="BRL" displayexchangerate="undefined" originalprice="268">
                           R$ 268,00
                        </p>
                        <p class="priceSufixx">Diária</p>
                     </div>
                  </label>
               </li>
               <li class="roomsgroup_room price price_odd hide" roomhashkey="484741">
                  <label>
                     <input type="radio" name="room-1214192-0" class="select_btn room buy selected" roomhashkey="484741">
                     <div>
                        <p class="name">Standard Triplo</p>
                        <p class="services">Cafe da Manha</p>
                        <a href="#" class="imageRoom more_pics showImagesRoom">SELECIONADO</a>
                        <p class="price price-exchange" originalcurrency="BRL" displayexchangerate="undefined" originalprice="335">
                           R$ 335,00
                        </p>
                        <p class="priceSufixx">Diária</p>
                     </div>
                  </label>
               </li>
            </ul>
            <a href="#" class="open_rooms hotel btnSeeRooms show" title="Mostrar mais quartos">Mostrar mais quartos</a>
            <a href="#" class="hide hide_rooms" title="Esconder Quartos">Esconder Quartos</a>
         </div>
      </div>
      <p class="price">
         <a href="#" class="purchase" title="Selecionar">SELECIONADO</a>
      </p>
   </div>
   <div class="hotel_map"></div>
   <div class="hotelDetailsIFrameContainer iframe"></div>
   <div class="hotel_observations"></div>
   <div class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-front ui-draggable ui-resizable" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" style="display: none; position: absolute;" aria-describedby="ui-id-19" aria-labelledby="ui-id-20">
      <div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix ui-draggable-handle">
         <span id="ui-id-20" class="ui-dialog-title">&nbsp;</span>
         <button type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only ui-dialog-titlebar-close" role="button" title="Close">
            <span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-closethick"></span>
            <span class="ui-button-text">Close</span>
         </button>
      </div>
      <div class="hotel_gallery ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" id="ui-id-19" style="display: block;"></div>
      <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-n" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
      <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
      <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
      <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-w" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
      <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
      <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-sw" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
      <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-ne" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
      <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-nw" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
   </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Usar JQuery para trocar textos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/329660/usar-jquery-para-trocar-textos)

Comment: Não bro... Antes era só trocar o texto de um elemento. Agora to tentando aplicar o que aprendi na ultima, na questão dos "on click" e funcionou. Porém trocou o texto de todos os botões e depois que clica, nunca mais volta...

Comment: Gabriel, depois que você troca o texto do elemento o javascript sobrescreve o anterior. Você vai precisar trocar o texto manualmente depois.
E o jQuery muda o texto de todos os elementos que casarem com o selector, se você usou o seletor de classes, exemplo `.minha-classe`, todos os elementos com essa classe vão mudar. Você vai ter que usar um seletor mais específico ou afunilar esta seleção manualmente.

Comment: Entendi. Como eles são identicos em tudo, não vai funcionar. Qual o nome da função que faz "subir a pagina"? E pra aplica-la consigo fazer do mesmo jeito que o Sam me passou na outra quest?

Comment: Sam, aparentemente a difereça deles é a li que depois da class tem uma "hashkey" que tem um numero diferente em cada uma. Acredito que isto não seja HTML puro.

Comment: Não está muito claro. Tem uns botões diferentes do outro. Por exemplo, esse aqui só tem um: `<a href="#" class="purchase" title="Selecionar">SELECIONADO</a>`, e esse aqui vários: `<a href="#" class="imageRoom more_pics showImagesRoom">SELECIONADO</a>`